# How to write an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, asynchronous-javascript

I'm doing my first ever react website and I need help to write an asynchronous JavaScript function.
Here I'm uploading the user input files to a firebase storage and then making a post request to the API to store the data on the database. However, since the firebase upload takes some time to upload the data to its storage, the API request happens before the upload finishes, therefore the data does not get uploaded to the db. Now I know I should use promises of async await keywords here, but I can't figure out how to. I'd appreciate if someone could help. Thanks in advance!

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```js
const save = (items) => {
  items.forEach((item) => {
    const fileName = new Date().getTime() + item.label + item.file.name;
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`/items/${fileName}`).put(item.file);
    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log("Upload is" + progress + "% done.");
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      },
      () => {
        storage.ref("items").child(fileName).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          setSong((prev) => {
            return { ...prev, [item.label]: url };
          });
        });
      }
    );
  })
  console.log(song)
  axios.post("songs/create", song);
}
```

PS: Here, items is the array of input files from the user, each file is with a label and it is how the attributes are named on the json document.
setSong is a useState function. Here The JSON document already contains the other user inputs(which are not files), and the setSong method is used to append the firebase URLs of the files to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for all files to get uploaded then you can call your API, in order to do that you should use `Promise.all` to wait to resolve  all files  :

```
  const save = items => {
  Promise.all(
    items.map(item => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        const fileName = new Date().getTime() + item.label + item.file.name
        const uploadTask = storage.ref(`/items/${fileName}`).put(item.file)
        uploadTask.on(
          'state_changed',
          snapshot => {
            const progress =
              (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
            console.log('Upload is' + progress + '% done.')
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err)
          },
          () => {
            storage
              .ref('items')
              .child(fileName)
              .getDownloadURL()
              .then(url => {
                setSong(prev => {
                  return { ...prev, [item.label]: url }
                })
                resolve({[item.label]: url})
              })
          }
        )
      })
    })
  ).then((res) => {
    const song = {}
    res.forEach(item => {
      return {
        ...song,
        ...item
      }
    })
    axios.post('songs/create', song)
  })
}
```

Comment: It throws an error on the console, says "Invalid argument count in `on`: Expected between 1 and 4 arguments, received 5.' "

Comment: I changed my answer by using Promise.all, I used it because it's the best solution for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

### Functions and Async

Async/Await can be implemented wherever a function starts. Functions can be written in following forms:

```js
function name(){};
function name() => {};
```

To write an async function, you would do the following:

```js
async function name(){};
```

All of these functions are called functions though, to make functions run without calling them, we need to turn them into [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)'s, or Immediately Invoked Function Execution. If you want to create a function and execute it immediately you would surround the function in `()`'s and end it with an `();`.

```js
(function () {})();
```

If we simplify this:

```js
(() => {})();
```

Implementing async would go like this:

```js
(async () => {})();
```

### Await

The `await` operator is used to wait for a `Promise`, puting `await` in front of an expression that uses promises makes it wait for the promise. If it is used in front of an expression that doesn't use promises, it is redundant and your code editor/IDE will say so.

```js
(async () => {
    const str = await 'some string';
    console.log(str);
})();
```

`await` is redundant here since the expression `'some string'` does not relate to a promise, but a string.

```js
(async () => {
  const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    resolve('some string')
  );

  const str = await myPromise.then(x => console.log(x));
})();
```

`await` is properly used here since the expression `myPromise` is related to a promise that outputs a string.

## Implementation

I'm not 100% sure how the api works within promises, I recommend you figure it out yourself, but this is my educated guess:

```js
const save = (items) => {
  Promise.all(
    items.map((item) => {
      return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        const fileName = new Date().getTime() + item.label + item.file.name;
        const uploadTask = await storage
          .ref(`/items/${fileName}`)
          .put(item.file);
        await uploadTask.on(
          "state_changed",
          (snapshot) => {
            const progress =
              (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log("Upload is" + progress + "% done.");
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          },
          async () => {
            await storage
              .ref("items")
              .child(fileName)
              .getDownloadURL()
              .then((url) => {
                setSong((prev) => {
                  return { ...prev, [item.label]: url };
                });
                resolve({ [item.label]: url });
              });
          }
        );
      });
    })
  ).then(async (res) => {
    const song = {};
    res.forEach((item) => {
      return {
        ...song,
        ...item,
      };
    });
    await axios.post("songs/create", song);
  });
};
```

Comment: Yes but can you give me a help on where how to use the await keyword in this example?

Comment: Honestly I just spam await everywhere unless it tells me it's redundant to use there, but I'll update the answer.

Comment: Complete, let me know if anything is unclear.